# Angular Routing - Named route outlet - can't navigate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, router-outlet

**Q:** Pls. help to figure out how to leverage the named outlet in my case.

I've tried out several approaches, but it didn't work for me:

- Set as not empty string top route, due to module lazy loading nature
- Apply different combination of names for 'right-sidebar' outlet

**Navigation code:**

```
 this.router.navigate(
            [
                {
                    outlets: {
                        primary: ['dashboard/accounting/operations'],
                        'right-sidebar': ['operations'] ?? what path should be here ??
                    }
                }
            ]);
```

[image][[image]]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your module routing the second operations should be renamed to operations_crud.

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: 
   {primary: ['dashboard/accounting/operations'],
             'right-sidebar': ['operations_crud'] 
   }
}]);
```